# subset data by year given dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: r, date, subset

I am trying to subset my data by years but i'm given daily points, something like what i'm given below.

```
sell  Buy Country Date
0.00  25.00 AA 17/03/2005
9.09  45.45 AA 16/12/2004
9.09  45.45 AA 16/04/2009
18.18 27.27 AA 18/11/2004
```

I would like the subset for year 2004 and should get

```
sell  Buy Country Date
18.18 27.27 AA 18/11/2004
9.09  45.45 AA 16/12/2004
```

Is there a code or function that can do this?

Cheers

Comment: If your dates are formatted as dates, a normal subset works with `lubridate::year`: `df[year(df$Date) == 2004,]`

Comment: @GauravTaneja `as.Date` is from base R, not `lubridate`

Comment: Thanks @Procrastinatus Maximus , I think alistaire's comment covers it so have deleted mine.

Answer (score 2):

I would always ensure that Date fields are in Date format.
Then you could use Base R subseting to filter rows

Assume df is your data.frame

**Base R:**

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, '%d/%m/%Y')
df[format(df$Date, '%Y') == "2005", ]
```

**Dplyr:**

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, format(df$Date, '%Y') == "2005")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `substr` and `subset`

```
subset(df1, substr(Date, nchar(Date)-3, nchar(Date)) == 2004)
#   sell   Buy Country       Date
#2  9.09 45.45      AA 16/12/2004
#4 18.18 27.27      AA 18/11/2004
```

Or another approach with `data.table` and `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[year(dmy(Date))==2004]
#    sell   Buy Country       Date
#1:  9.09 45.45      AA 16/12/2004
#2: 18.18 27.27      AA 18/11/2004
```